# How to sum values in one column excluding cells with duplicate text values in a different column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a basic issue at hand. In the following exemplary table with one text-value column and one number-value column:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| juice | 5 |
| peanuts | 2 |
| walnuts | 3 |
| juice | 5 |
| pineapples | 8 |

I want to sum the numbers in the number-value column, excluding the ones which have the same value in the name-value column on the same row (i.e. juice), the sum being 18. Obviously it is a given that the number corresponds to the name each time the name is given.

And what would have to change in the formula if the numbers were also different, like here:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| juice | 5 |
| peanuts | 2 |
| walnuts | 3 |
| juice | 6 |
| pineapples | 8 |
| juice | 5 |

In such a scenario, I would like to exclude the one *exact duplicate*: juice-5,  and count it as one instance in the calculation. The answer in the sum would now be 24.

EDIT: I have a similar table to this:

[image: 1]

Below I have the sum of the numbers according to each initial in column A. For example:
`C10` `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A8="B") *(C1:C8))`

I'd like to exclude all the duplicates (i.e. coloured in yellow) in terms of all three variables by making them count as one. Thus, C10 would be 5 instead of 7. What do I add to the formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS as a divisor.  This way only 1/2 of each `juice 5` is added resulting in only `5`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B6/COUNTIFS(A1:A6,A1:A6,B1:B6,B1:B6))
```

[image]

If one has the Dynamic Array formula UNIQUE:

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(A1:B6),0,2))
```

This will return the unique values and sum the second column.

[image]

---

As per your edit:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A1:A6="B") *(C1:C6))/(COUNTIFS(B1:B6,B1:B6,C1:C6,C1:C6,A1:A6,"=B")+(A1:A6<>"B")))
```

Dynamic array version:

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:C6,A1:A6="B")),0,3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the edit of my post! I should specify the context in which I am trying to do this operation, because I can't seem to use your solution at the moment.

Comment: @Chris see edits.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That did the trick!

Comment: @Chris  if this worked for you, remember to choose one as the correct answer by clicking the check mark by the answer you feel is best.

Comment: Sorry, I have too little "reputation" to cast votes...

Comment: But you can mark correct by clicking the ✔ mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about you detect duplicates with a helper column or two?

Say you have data in A to C and if all three A to C values occurred together before, then the helper column should be zero, if not the value in C. Now, if you can sort your data (custom sort, multi-level first by A, then B and then C), then all the duplicates will always be right below each other.

So in D1 put (and copy down)

```
=IF(AND(A1=A2,B1=B2,C1=C2),0,C2)
```

Now proceed to sumif column D as per your example.

If you can't sort, you must add another help column (say E) with the following:

```
=A1 & B1 & C1
```

And with D1 `=C1`, then D2 becomes (copy downwards)

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E2,$E$1:E1,0)),0,C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, you can refer to this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((MATCH(IF($A$1:$A$8=E1,$B$1:$B$8&$C$1:$C$8,NA()),IF($A$1:$A$8=E1,$B$1:$B$8&$C$1:$C$8,NA()),)=ROW($1:$8))*$C$1:$C$8,0))
```

[image]